# Product Attributes not visible in Akeneo 2.0

Tags: product, pim, akeneo

This is a typical case of: "it worked yesterday, but now not anymore". No matter what I try, when adding a new product I only see the 'SKU' field. I've added a couple of attributes, created extra attribute groups, but still: when adding a new or editing an existing product I don't see any of the other attribute / groups.

What could cause this?

These are my fixtures:

```
attributes.csv:
code;label-en_US;label-fr_FR;label-nl_NL;label-de_DE;allowed_extensions;auto_option_sorting;available_locales;date_max;date_min;decimals_allowed;default_metric_unit;group;localizable;max_characters;max_file_size;metric_family;minimum_input_length;negative_allowed;number_max;number_min;reference_data_name;scopable;sort_order;type;unique;useable_as_grid_filter;validation_regexp;validation_rule;wysiwyg_enabled
sku;SKU;;;;;;;;;;;other;0;;;;;;;;;0;0;pim_catalog_identifier;1;1;;;
name;Name;Nom;Naam;Name;;;de_DE,en_US,fr_FR,nl_NL;;;;;default;1;;;;;;;;;0;0;pim_catalog_text;0;0;;;
color;Color;;Kleur;;;1;;;;;;properties;0;;;;;;;;;0;0;pim_catalog_simpleselect;0;0;;;
description;;;;;;;;;;;;default;1;;;;;;;;;0;0;pim_catalog_textarea;0;0;;;1

attribute_options.csv:
code;label-de_DE;label-en_US;label-fr_FR;label-nl_NL;attribute;sort_order
red;Rot;Red;Rouge;Rood;color;1
green;Grein;Green;Verde;Groen;color;1
blue;Blau;Blue;Bleu;Blauw;color;1

attribute_groups.csv
code;label-en_US;label-fr_FR;label-de_DE;label-nl_NL;attributes;sort_order
other;Other;Autre;Other;Overige;sku;2
default;Default;Default;Default;Standaard;name,description;0
properties;Properties;;;Eigenschappen;color;1

channels.csv
code;label-en_US;label-de_DE;label-fr_FR;label-nl_NL;conversion_units;currencies;locales;tree
ecommerce;Webshop;Webshop;Webshop;Webshop;;EUR;de_DE,en_US,fr_FR,nl_NL;master
```

Comment: The first explanation would be *families*, did you select a family when creating your products ?  
Does the existing products have a family ?

Comment: I have set a family, but it turned out that my product attributes were not present in the family. It works now. Thanks. Feel free to add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a family to your products in order to see the attributes.
[*See first comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942454/product-attributes-not-visible-in-akeneo-2-0?noredirect=1#comment82870579_47942454)